# Django model TimeField views.py cannot select hour or minute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

When using a TimeField in a Django model I wish to be able to perform a query in a view, using the hour and minute elements of the TimeField separately.

However, when I do so, if I run the view I receive an error message that the `__hour` (or `__minute`) does not exist (see code below):

```
scheduleItems = DEVICESCHEDULE.objects.filter(time__hour = nowHour)
```

If I change the model to use a `DateTimeField` rather than a `TimeField`, I am able to use the `__hour` and `__minute` options.

I would prefer to keep the field type as a `TimeField`, as I only need a time to be input and inputting a date (even if it is ignored) is confusing to the user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the date/time related lookups only works with dates and datetimes, not the time fields, although seems like it would be a nice feature to have as well.

Have you thought about raising a ticket maybe?

Maybe you can consider this as a replacement:

```
DEVICESCHEDULE.objects.extra(where=['SUBSTR(time, 1, 2)=%0.2d'], params=[nowHour])
DEVICESCHEDULE.objects.extra(where=['SUBSTR(time, 4, 2)=%0.2d'], params=[nowMinute])
```